# syntax error in a WSH script

Tags: wsh

I'm writing a script tp send automatically a pdf file, when it has been wroten into a certain folder.
It works nearly but If I had an attachment I get a syntax error
It I put the name of the file as constant in the code, it works with the attachment.
But as soon as I take the name of the found file it does not work.
Here is my code. The error is "800401E4 CDO.Message.1"

```
FOLDER_PDF = "T:\MBö\AusdruckLieferverzug" 
FOLDER_MOVE = "T:\MBö\AusdruckLieferverzug\Sent" 

set lobj_cdomsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strPDFs = "" 
For Each file In objFSO.GetFolder(FOLDER_PDF).Files 
    If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(file.Path)) = "pdf" Then 
        strPDFs = """" & file.Path & """"  
    End If 
    lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "mail04.provider.de"
    lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465

    lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "testperson@firma.de"
    lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "xxxxxx"
    lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465  ' 


    lobj_cdomsg.To = "testperson@apt.de"
    lobj_cdomsg.From = "testperson@apt.de"
    lobj_cdomsg.Subject = "Lieferverzug"
    lobj_cdomsg.TextBody = "Bitte finden Sie als Anlage eine PDF-Datei mit den Artikeln, die im Lieferverzug sind." &  vbCRLF 

    strCmd = "lobj_cdomsg.AddAttachment " &  strPDFs 
    WScript.Echo strCmd
    lobj_cdomsg.AddAttachment strPDFs
    'The following code works but not the code line before, although the content of strPDFs is exactly the same
    'lobj_cdomsg.AddAttachment "T:\MBö\AusdruckLieferverzug\tesdatei.pdf"
    'objFile.Close
    ' Dann ganzes abschicken

    lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Update
    lobj_cdomsg.Send
    Set lobj_cdomsg = Nothing

Next
```

Can you help me to find the error, please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CDO.Message.1 error '80040220'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391500/cdo-message-1-error-80040220)

Answer (score 0):

I found the error:

It was the command:
  strPDFs = """" & file.Path & """"

It works if I don't add the quotations marks.
The right syntax is:  strPDFs = file.Path

....
   lobj_cdomsg.AddAttachment strPDFs

I hope it can be usefull for somebody else.